# How can I set up a FTP server on Windows XP without using IIS?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp

Is there any way that I can configure an FTP server on my current Windows XP installation without using IIS?

Answer (score 7):

There are plenty of third party ftp servers available. Personally I'd suggest [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) which can be downloaded for free from the [FileZilla website](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server).

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/) for several years. It supports a wide range of platforms and protocols and has a wide range of options. It's not free but is very reasonably priced (and has a free trial available as well) and my experience with support has been great.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), a very useful freeware search tool that can also act as a tiny FTP or HTTP server.